# Where is the "See Pages Feed" on my Facebook pages?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

A few days ago, the "See Pages Feed" on my Facebook pages simply disappeared. I have been searching frantically finding out what happened -- and how to access posts from Pages I've liked via my Page(s).

To no avail.

This really throws me for a loop. Suddenly, I cannot access the posts without going to individual pages. That's not only cumbersome, yet also I am sure I am missing lots of great posts.

Do you have the answer?
I am trying this via my PC -- not my mobile phone.

Comment: p.s. O yes, and I am trying this via my PC -- not my mobile phone.

Answer (score 1):

Try this URL:

```
business.facebook.com/YOURPAGENAME/pages_feed/
```

So if your business' name is Yellow Puppy Foundation, type `business.facebook.com/YellowPuppyFoundation/pages_feed/`

If you aren't running a business page, use this URL

```
facebook.com/YOURPAGENAME/pages_feed/
```